# Need Help with SharePoint List view weird behavior?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter

I have a list in SharePoint online and I am trying to filter using the registration numbers and want to display all the registration numbers greater than 3000 (3001-3600) on a view. The total number of registrations(items) is 3600. When I filter the list saying Show items only greater than 3000, it displays all items from 3001-3600 but also displays registrations 1-999.

I have tried re-indexing the registration ID column.

Comment: Is this a Single Line of Text or Number column?

Comment: Is this column a list column(created in this list) or a site column? Compare the results if using below filter:  registration numbers greater than 3000 AND registration numbers less than 3600. Also try to clear the cache then have a test.

Comment: It is a Site Column and I have tried filtering greater than 3000 and less than 4999, but it still shows registrations between 0-999.

Answer (score -1):

do you have multiple filters? if so, there seems to be a bug. below is a link to a similar issue.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Multiple-Filters-in-a-SharePoint-Online-Custom-List/td-p/100612